# Perturbation of Elliptic operator

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, differential-operators, schrodinger-operators

Let $\Omega$ be an open region or a non-compact complete manifold, $L$ be an elliptic operator with possibly non  vanishing  zero-order term, e.g. $-\Delta+q$.  Suppose $W$ is an operator such that $W(x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$.

**Q** I do not understand the following statements.

1. $W$ defines a relatively compact perturbation of the operator of $L$.
2. $L+W$ has the same essential spectrum as $L$, and may have  only isolated eigenvalues of finite multiplicity outside the essential spectrum.

PS:
 I saw the above in the paper: **Periodic Nonlinear Schrodinger Equations with Application to Photonic Crystals**, A. Pankov(Section 5). The author(Pankov) gave the reference of, Simon's **Schrodinger semigroups** Theore C3.1, 3.5. But Simon gave the reference of T. Kato's **Perturbation of Linear operator**, but I did not follow which parts or theorems the authors used in the Book[Perturbation of Linear operator] to show the statements.

Comment: What do you mean by $W(x) \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$? Is $x$ a point on your manifold or is $x$ a point in the function space? You can find a discussion of the implication 1 $\implies$ 2 in Reed-Simon's "Methods of modern mathematical physics", volume 4, section XIII.4

Comment: As $x\to\infty$, $W(x)$ tends to the zero-operator. $x$ is a point in the base space.manifold.